# RecyclerView só lista dados quando interage com outros componentes

Tags: android-recyclerview

Estou com problemas para exibir o resultado de uma consulta no firebase no RecyclerView, só exibi o resultado quando eu clico dentro do componente EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Solução:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Explicação:

O wrap_content ainda não é totalmente suportado, existem meios de fazer funcionar, mas não é seguro.

Fonte: https://medium.com/@elye.project/recyclerview-supported-wrap-content-not-quite-f04a942ce624